# Get ID of last inserted row and use it to insert into another table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following stored procedure which we use to insert data into a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mySproc
(
 invoiceId IN NUMBER
 customerId IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO myTable (INVOICE_ID) 
    VALUES (invoiceId);
END mySproc;
/
```

What I am trying to do is to get the last inserted ID (this is the primary key field on myTable and auto incremented using a sequence) and insert it into another table, I have tried the following but could not get it working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mySproc
(
 invoiceId IN NUMBER
 customerId IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO myTable (INVOICE_ID) 
    VALUES (invoiceId)

    returning id into v_id;

    INSERT INTO anotherTable (ID, customerID) 
    VALUES (v_id, customerId);  
END mySproc;
/
```

I am getting this error: **[Error] PLS-00049 (59: 26): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'V_ID'** I think I need to declare v_id somewhere but I tried before and after the BEGIN statement but that gave another error.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have race conditions, why not fetch the last Id from the sequence. Sequence.CURRVAL if I'm not mistaking. Either that or fetch the biggest Id in the table (auto-increment, so biggest = last Id inserted).

Comment: @Sam: currval is always safe and doesn't suffer from race conditions - it returns the same value most recently returned by nextval in that session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your procedure to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mySproc
(
 invoiceId IN NUMBER,  -- Added comma
 customerId IN NUMBER
)
IS
    v_id  NUMBER;  -- ADDED
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO myTable (INVOICE_ID) 
    VALUES (invoiceId)
    returning id into v_id;

    INSERT INTO anotherTable (ID, customerID) 
    VALUES (v_id, customerId);  
END mySproc;
```

Share and enjoy.