# Insert id from from one table and insert it into another one. Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a register user form and I have two tables in mysql. What I want to do is when a new user has registered, take the id (which primary key) of that user and insert it into another table. What is the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: If you're using `auto_increment` primary keys, use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: you should distinguish first what are your preferred ways of getting it to execute your second insert query . will you use serversidelanguage to generate it and execute your next insert query or direct it to mysql using stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use mysql_insert_id for this purpose. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First insert the user details into users table and get inserted user id using `mysql_insert_id`. and use that user id to insert into another table.

Answer (score 1):

**AS ON GETTING IT ON PHP**

GET LAST INSERT ID [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

**BUT IF YOU INTEND TO GET IT USING MYSQL QUERY**

use stored procedure to store last insert id to a variable then generete your second query

```
INSERT INTO T1 (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2); 
SET @last_id_in_T1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO T2 (col1,col2) VALUES (@last_id_in_T1,val2);
```

or direct insert after your first insert

```
 INSERT INTO T1 (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2); 
INSERT INTO T2 (col1,col2) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),val2);
```

Comment: Thanks, the LAST_INSERT_ID() worked for me. I have another question: I have two tables, the first table collect the basic info about the user (firstname, lastname, etc..). Once the user has entered the info, they are taken to another page where they need to complete the registration. This is where the info they submit goes into the second table. The first row in the second table is the  FOREIGN KEY of Primary ID in the first table which LAST_INSERT_ID() is used for. Now, how do I go about inserting the info users submit in the second table? DO i use UPDATE or INSERT INTO statements?

Comment: since you did insert the same id into the second table only using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` use update to that id`s other null columns value

Answer (score 0):

Use any of transaction query for writing:

Following is in CI pattern:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
if(!$this->db->trans_complete()){
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1= "INSERT INTO employee ( username, email,...)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', ...)";
        if($result1 = mysql_query($query1))
        {
            $emp_id = mysql_insert_id(); // last created id by above query

            $query2= "INSERT INTO dept ( emp_id, dept_name, ...)
            VALUES ('".$emp_id."', '".$_POST["dept_name"]."',...)";

            if($result2 = mysql_query($query2))
            {
                //success msg
            }
        }
```

Comment: This snippet uses insecure/unstable query practices and should not be used.  Prepared statements should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Another neat way to do it at do it at Database level itself is to used [Stored Procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)

Look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17968741/302987) to see an example of how to do it. You will have to check how Stored procedures work in your specific database to get the specific syntax. This makes it error free even if someone refactors or moves around the code and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using trigger the Mysql on database-level. For example, I have two tables:

```
user(id int primary key, nombre varchar(50));

replication(id_r int primary key, nombre_r varchar(50));
```

Using the trigger:

```
create trigger user_r after insert on user
for each row
insert into replication(id_r, nombre_r)
select u.id, u.nombre
from user u
where u.id=NEW.id and u.nombre=NEW.nombre;
```